# How to create a link on a marked item?

Tags: qgis

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.x and QGIS 1.74 on a Windows XP SP3 System. In ArcGIS I get XML-Data which can be converted to a file-gdb using "IP NAS-Manager".

Included in the XML-files there a owner informations which are stored in a kind of database, labelled filename.data.db, filename.index.db, filename.log.db and so on.

Using ArcGIS 10.x and the extensions "IP ALKIS- Karte" and "IP-ALKIS Buch" it is possible, to show owner information in a separate window. To do this, you must start "IP ALKIS-Buch" before you start ArcGIS 10.x and log on to a Tomcat-Server to verify, that you are a registered user. In ArcGIS 10.x now you select the desired extension, point and click to an item and will get the associated information of owner name, creation-date, length, width etc. of the selected item. All works fine, no problem.

Now I'm trying to get the same information using QGIS, but I don't know the kind of database, where the owner information is stored.

Fortunately, there is another way to get the information. The administration "Kreis" offers "Map Solution" to get the owner information. They also sent me a link to their web-service, where I can log in and search for information. This link can be modified by the item-number I want to search for.

And now comes the problem: How can I realise, that

1. there is a way to use the link especially to connect to the desired website?
2. the selected item can be handed over to the link?

The result should be similar to the result of clicking on an item with the "information" button selected and the associated table-information will be displayed.

I hope, I could get you a glimpse of what I'm intending to do, otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: I think, I've got it! According to [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUxkddOP3BQ&feature=related) I defined an action in the Properties-Tab using Internet Explorer for browsing to the specific site. Passing the item-description as search argument will still be a little bit tricky, but I think I can get it done.